# jquery select2: TypeError: b.dataAdapter is null

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

when using the select2 multiselect and selecting an option I get this error message displayed:

```
TypeError: b.dataAdapter is null
```

Does anyone know what this is about?

The multiselect works fine, I just wonder about this message.

EDIT:

This is my html:

```html
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-md-12" for="participant-id">Participant    
        <span class="required"> * </span>
    </label>
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <input type="hidden" name="participant_id" value=""/>
        <select name="participant_id[]" multiple="multiple" class="form-control select2me participantSelector" required="required" id="participant-id">
            <option value=""></option>
        </select>
    </div>                                
</div>
```

this is the jquery init:

```js
$(".select2me").select2({
    placeholder:"Select",
    width:"auto",
    allowClear:!0
});
```

The data for the multiselect I get if a value is chosen in another dropdown 'projectSelector':

```js
$('.projectSelector').on('change', function() {
    var targetProject_id = $('#project-id :selected').val();
    updateParticpantDropdown(targetProject_id);
});


function updateParticpantDropdown(selectedProjectId){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/xx/projects/xx/'+ selectedProjectId,
        dataType : "json",
        success: function (response, status) {
            if (response.result == "success"){
                var data = response.data;
                $(".participantSelector").empty().select2({
                    placeholder: "Click here to select participants",
                    allowClear: false,
                    data: data
                });
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Data is getting loaded into the multiselect and everythings works as expected on the screen. Just in the console I get the error messsage of

```
TypeError: b.dataAdapter is null
```

This is my json response (in short):

```
{
    "result":"success",
    "data":[
        {"id":18,"text":"xx, Ana Rosa"},
        {"id":17,"text":"xx, Saul"},
        {"id":14,"text":"xx, Jesus"},
        {"id":15,"text":"xx, Jose Sergio"},
        {"id":13,"text":"xx, Guadalupe"},
        {"id":12,"text":"xx, Adolfo"},
        {"id":25,"text":"xx, Roland"},
        {"id":16,"text":"xx, Mariela Elisa"},
        {"id":11,"text":"xx, Roberto Carlos "},
        {"id":19,"text":"xx, Jose Rafael"},
        {"id":2,"text":"xx, Juan Carlos"}
    ]
}
```

In Chrome I get this message:

```
select2.full.min.js:2 
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'current' of null
    at HTMLSelectElement.<anonymous> (select2.full.min.js:2)
    at HTMLSelectElement.dispatch (jquery.min.js:3)
    at HTMLSelectElement.r.handle (jquery.min.js:3)
    at Object.trigger (jquery.min.js:3)
    at HTMLSelectElement.<anonymous> (jquery.min.js:3)
    at Function.each (jquery.min.js:2)
    at n.fn.init.each (jquery.min.js:2)
    at n.fn.init.trigger (jquery.min.js:3)
    at d.select (select2.full.min.js:1)
    at d.select (select2.full.min.js:2)
```

Comment: Please post your html for the select element and the js code you use to initialize the select2 plugin.

Comment: I've created a fiddle, but I've couldn't reproduce your issue. No errors in Chrome: https://jsfiddle.net/01zb15mq/.

Comment: I think I get the same problem when I try to update my select2 with different tags.

I have checked this from firefox and chrome. Both throw erros:
 # chrome Version 56.0.2924.87
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'current' of null`

 # firefox 51.0.1
`TypeError: b.dataAdapter is null`

The jsfiddle is available from: https://jsfiddle.net/PBrockmann/74v2gzhe/

Comment: Can you load the unminified library and see if you can get more context for the error?  You are loading "select2.full.min.js:2 " which is minified.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 4):

Since selector2 elements tend to store some additional data, I've noticed when the data of the list element is cleared in addition to `$(".participantSelector").empty()` the error is gone. So, try it out this way:

```
var selector = $(".participantSelector");
selector.empty();
selector.removeData();
selector.select2({
    placeholder: "Click here to select participants",
    allowClear: false,
    data: data
});
```

Hopefully, it works for you too.

Comment: I'm having this problem and sadly your suggestion did not solve it

Comment: @LucileDT, as usual in programming, there is no unique recipe. If you expand on the problem you've run into, I or someone else might lend you a helping hand here

Comment: Thanks, it was not a reproach, sorry if it sounded that way :x I'll ask a new question if I have the time to explain my problem

Answer (score 2):

you should remove .empty() and use like below. it is working fine for you..

```
$(".participantSelector").select2({
   placeholder: "Click here to select participants",
   allowClear: false,
   data: data
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a problem because you have initialized select drop down with a null value. Basically, script telling you to drop down is initialize but there is no data in it. As a solution please add one value

`<option value="0">Please Select</option>`

Rest of things seems like correct.